# Accessing $app inside Silex Shared Service

Tags: silex

I'm doing a shared service like this in my `app.php` file:

```
$app['rules'] = $app->share(function() use($app) {
    return new MyProject\Rules($app);
});
```

And then:

```
namespace MyProject;

use Silex\Application;

class Rules
{

    private $app;
    public $request;

    public function __construct(Application $app) {
        $this->app = $app;
    }


    public test() {
        print_r($this->app['something']);
    }
}
```

But when I access $app inside of `$app['rules']->test();` it's a new sort of version $app and it doesn't have the variables that I set later in `$app` from other parts of the application. Is there any way to access the parent `$app` instead of this inside version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are injecting the whole `$app` into the `Rules` constructor using a type hint `__construct(Application $app)` but instead of getting the `$app` injected by the DIC on call time, you are passing a variable `$app` in ti's current state (the `use` part).

You have to use one or the other, the way you are doing it overrides the type hint and passes the variable in the current state, no future properties will be injected.

By the way, you are injecting the whole container (Silex\Application). A better way to do it is to inject just the service/s you need.

```php
$app['rules'] = $app->share(function($app) { //$app is Injected automatically when called
    return new MyProject\Rules($app); //here you pass the whole container
    return new MyProject\Rules($app['something']); //here you pass only the required dependency
});
```

The code in `MyProject` is fine, leave the constructor as it is.

Comment: If I don't pass anything in `Rules()` it doesn't seem like there is any way to get access to $app inside of the Rules class. Are you suggesting `return new MyProject\Rules($app);` and `public function __construct($app)`? (I need the whole $app inside of my shared function.)

Comment: I'll update my answer with the code example to do what you want, but I strongly recommend you reading a bit more about how [Pimple](https://github.com/fabpot/Pimple) (the dependency injection container component of Silex) works to get a better understanding of how Silex works.

Comment: I've updated the code, if you take a close look, I'm not using `use` to pass the `$app`, it will be injected on call time by Silex.